# Any news on an SD reader for 12.04?

Tags: updates, sd-card

My Ubuntu 12.04 will not load an SD card.  That is to say, if I insert a simple SD card from my camera it does not show up and I cannot get to my pictures.  I can find lots of questions on the board asking about this, and the answers are not satisfactory.  Many of the threads just tail off with requests for printouts of data.  But no solution.  It would help Ubuntu to look more professional if this problem were just to be fixed with an update.

Comment: Open a terminal and post the output of lsusb.

Comment: family@Computer:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Comment: Oh dear, see what I mean.  AskUbuntu has no answer.  There seems to be no solution to this problem.  I think this is a big negative for Ubuntu, because the majority of users want to use sd chips.  Maybe this happens in just a few cases but to be a proper service it should be fixable, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 1 > sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

This command will rescan the the pci bus and look for changes.  Run it after you have inserted your SD into the computer.  This was a known bug in 12.04 (per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/995743) when using older kernels.  According to that bug report, this has been fixed since kernel v3.12-rc1.  You should be able to update your kernel to the most recent (3.13, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Hi ChrisR: I tried that command and unfortunately the SD card was not found.  Oh well!